# Discourage code dumps

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, new-users, source-code

Lately, I've seen a lot of ["this is my code, please find the bug"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790314) questions, i.e., people just dump their complete class file instead of creating a minimal working example.

When I see this, I usually leave a comment, pointing them to http://sscce.org or explaining how to create such an example (sometimes in vain, sometimes people actually go ahead and shorten their code a little bit).

Would it make sense to do something against this problem? For example, issue a warning when a new user tries to enter more the 20 lines of code, providing some hints on how to create a "good code sample"?

**EDIT**: It looks like a feature has been added to address this issue:

[How do you prevent "Here code. You fix." questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107058/138661)

Comment: Are you kidding? We're often _lucky_ to get any code at all!

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: Well, that's another problem (with the same cause: people not investing time in creating a good question).

Comment: Hmm, close votes seem like a good way to discourage this. We've got 50 of them now, thankfully I don't run out as quickly anymore.

Comment: Hello, I have been writing a code to represent MATLAB Cell Arrays in C and the code is working. But I would like an experienced coder to comment on the implementation, whether it may lead to problems in future, etc. How do I post a question about this on Stackoverflow?

Comment: @MaheshNarayanamurthi: Have a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the same way we show a red box that tells people their question is likely subjective and may get closed, it seems that adding a similar box on a code dump would help:

"Questions with large blocks of code typically get fewer good answers than questions which show the smallest portion of code that still generates the error.  [Consider following these suggestions.](http://sscce.org/)"

Although it would be better to link to a meta question which gives essentially the same info, but targeted to the SO audience.

Comment: I'm not convinced the cure isn't worse than the disease. This could lead to more questions where the only possible answer is “show us the code”.

Comment: @Gilles True.  On the other hand, the act of trying to explain the problem, rather than showing a large code block, sometimes makes one understand the problem and resolve it on their own.  But I guess it's a toss-up.  Which is worse - large code blocks which are essentially too long to read, nevermind debug, or questions with no code example?

Answer (score 12):

Warnings were made to be ignored. Most users barely take the time to format their posts, they can't even be bothered to use a spell checker. Adding even more documentation and warnings will achieve nothing.

Comment: +1 Downvote, vote to close if necessary, move on.