# Code dump and run

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, low-quality-posts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Discourage code dumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88842/discourage-code-dumps)

Maybe it's just in the iPhone tag where I tend to hang out, but I'm seeing an increasing number of people asking "questions" that are a very large block of code and maybe a single sentence saying that it doesn't work.

They tend to get dealt with as you'd expect: downvotes or comments suggesting elucidation on what they've tried (or, often, what the actual problem is).

I wonder if we could raise the question quality (and increase the likelihood of a good answer) by detecting this and requesting revisions?

Questions:

- Is this really as wide-spread as it feels to me?
- Would a simple "question is > n% code" work?
- Would that just encourage people to badly format their code and make their questions even worse?

Thoughts?

**Edit**: Looks like this has been addressed ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88842/discourage-code-dumps) [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107058/how-do-you-prevent-here-code-you-fix-questions)).

Comment: What we really need are more close votes on this sort of question. NARQ, Too Localized, or Not Constructive (since it often turns into a debugging session in comments); sometimes even Off Topic applies.

Comment: Yea, I agree with you that this is common. I'm fairly new here so I cant comment on its frequency but quite a few of the questions that I see in the iPhone/iPad/iOS tags are just: here is code, it doesn't work, fix it for me. Not to mention it seems that someone always has to come along to clean it up for them so its even semi-readable.

Comment: @Josh I think the system works better if people are coached to write better questions rather than other people closing bad ones after the event.

Comment: Seen lots.  Downvote, then NARQ on them.

Comment: For what it's worth, this isn't just the iPhone tag... Like Will suggests, downvote the questions and vote to close them. Failing that, use your moderator flags. These questions are just noise; you're only improving the site by eliminating them.

Comment: Closing and improvement are not mutually exclusive. If a question is not answerable but is amenable to editing to make it so, a close vote and a comment are the correct actions.

Comment: Sure, we can deal with poor quality questions by downvoting, closing or flagging them, but wouldn't it be better if those questions never made it into the system in the first place? That's what I'm trying to get at here.