# How did this "all code" question get around the quality filter?

Tags: bug, status-completed, low-quality-posts, quality-filter

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669815/how-to-do-loop) was posted with just a block of code. Entire body text of question below:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Result
{
public static void main (String[] args)
for(int i=0;i<Result.length;i++)
{
    String num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Insert 1st Number: ");
    String num2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Insert 2nd Number: ");
}
{
    int max=Result[0];
    for(int i=0;i<Result.length;i++)
    if(num1+num2>=10){
        System.out.println(" congratulations ");
    }
    else if(num1+num2<=10){
        System.out.println(" the sum is less than 10 ");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(" exit ");
        for(int i=0;i<Score.length;i++)
        output=output+Result[i]+" ";
    }
}
}
```

How did they get around the [filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107058/how-do-you-prevent-here-code-you-fix-questions/107068#107068) that stops people from posting just a wall of code?

Comment: Confused by the "support" tag... And, I guess, the question. You want the work-around to be documented? I would rather think you'd want it *removed*...

Comment: @Shog9 I want it removed too

Comment: Well, now that the original question has been deleted, it's hard to say...

Comment: This will be plugged in the next build; please award the tick to yourself - you were right on the money.

Answer (score 20):

I think I found the loophole:

Code that's been indented with tabs rather than four spaces apparently is not considered "code" by the algorithm, allowing me to posts questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675547/what-does-this-code-thing-mean).

It also doesn't seem like it matters where the tab indented code is. Code indented with tabs intermingled with code indented with 4 spaces is not considered "code" either.

Comment: Thanks, that'll be it. That should be trivial to fix later today.

Comment: @marc ah, we need to normalize from tabs to spaces for this check (Markdown does this, actually, but I think this check is before the raw post is "cooked").

Answer (score 13):

Indeed, that copy is blocked (whether formatted or unformatted). Our *best guess* is that there was a grace-period edit, from some artificial random text, that was then replaced with this.... wall. Consequently, we shall be amending the new-user rules for self-edits to ensure that the quality checks are still applied in this scenario.

---

Update; hmmm... while trying to "fix" this, it turns out that it is *already immune* to this - i.e. when I tried this as a self-edit locally, it told me where to go. The hunt continues!

Comment: I can only say it again: It's *fascinating* how resourceful people are.

Comment: If you can't work it out, you could try luring the secret out of him with the promise of the first [hacker badge](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/no-we-have-not-forgotten-about-the-hacker-badge/).

Comment: @Marc See my answer.