# Please expand the "you only posted code" filter to consider backticks

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-users, code-formatting

It [recently became more difficult](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107058/how-do-you-prevent-here-code-you-fix-questions) to post questions from newer users that are composed mostly of code.

It looks like you can simply use backticks to format text as code to bypass this restriction.  For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701676/can-anyone-decode-this-tell-me-how) (since deleted, only visible to 10k users) is a giant block of obfuscated Javascript and no explanation whatsoever outside of the title, "Can anyone decode this?"

The filter that blocks mostly-code questions should also take backticked sections of the post body into account when considering the code:not-code ratio.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sigh; people are annoyingly inventive when it comes to getting around these things. The next build will include a strengthened version of this check, that uses all of the core markdown=>markup rendering, rather that trying to "fake it" with a quick glance at the unprocessed markdown. Or in other words - this won't be possible after the next deploy (it correctly identifies that example as *zero* context).