# How can we chat in the Android room?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, chat, android

I have a question that no-one is able to answer. I have struggled a lot with it. I need to talk to someone online so that I can discuss my problem. I think the Android room on SO chat would be the best place for this, but it is not allowing me to chat, even though I have the necessary reputation. Why? How can I discuss my problem with more experienced people?

Answer (score 24):

There are a couple of guys, including me, that review the access requests to the Android chatroom.

Some time ago the Android room was facing a lot of issues like trolls, spam etc. So we have decided to turn this room into a Gallery

The reasons why you've not been given access are :

- You've been spamming questions, some of them are [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937444/difficulty-in-replying-backlocation-of-second-user-to-a-first-users-message) of questions you've asked earlier.
- You've been posting [walls of codes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107058/how-do-you-prevent-here-code-you-fix-questions)
- You made [another account](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/927297/code-hacker) to ask questions, which has been now removed.

What you should do is:

- Search Stackoverflow for answers, before you ask a question. Most of your question, sorry to say are not something new. They have been solved, several times even, on Stackoverflow.
- Avoid walls of code, if possible. Try to use snippets of code. Explain them well, most of the time you will solve your own question in the process of composing it.
- If a question isn't receiving attention, [try editing it to improve it](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

  Also, chat is not tech support. We try to use the Android room to discuss higher level concepts. There are other [Android rooms](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/700397#700397) that may help you. I wouldn't recommend them though.

That said, we do help out new guys, provided that they respect the rules.

If you are interested, here are some of the chat rules that nil proposed:

- [Rules 1 & 2](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1699589#1699589)
- [Rule 3](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1718817#1718817)

Once you improve upon these points and get the hang of using Stackoverflow properly we will be happy to accept you :)

Comment: A wise decision. ---

Answer (score 7):

There appears to be a "Request Access" button at the bottom of the Android chat page? Try using that

Comment: Only users nominated by the room owner may talk here. See the faq for more information. You have requested talk privileges in this room; please be patient while the room owner processes your request. What does this mean?

Comment: Seems pretty self-explanatory, @code_hacker. Wait until the room owner approves your access.

Comment: @code_hacker, Michael is right, you just have to wait. The reason for this is that there have been some spam and flame issues in Android rooms in the past.

Comment: makes you still wonder, is there a notification when the room owner (? - I was unaware that there is any, now I see) actually denies a request? So you can know whether you were denied of request or maybe it's just not processed yet.

Comment: @naxa We usually let the person know they were rejected and why they were rejected (unless I'm bored and would rather say you worship false gods [i.e., not Enki] than remind you that you probably don't fit the description in the rules, though a few overly sensitive people got mad when I did that), but if it's been a while since you requested access, we might also just remove your request so the next time you're around and request access, we can check it.