# Pure code question evading the “Here code. You fix.” filter

Tags: feature-request, filtering

A [question on SO (10k-only link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378497/syntax-error-in-python) that recently got some attention due to a meta post consisted entirely of python code, no additional text was present in the question body. This should theoretically have triggered the [“Here code. You fix.” filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107058/how-do-you-prevent-here-code-you-fix-questions) that should prevent questions that only contain source code.

This didn't work in this case, the entire question body was:

```
    import math
def is_Prime(x):

    if ((x&1)) :
        for c in range (2,int(math.sqrt(x),+1)
                        if ( x%c == 0 ):
                          print ("not prime")






is_Prime(77)
```

I'm wondering if the whitespace might have thrown the filter off. There might be a loophole here to evade the filter. If it's an easy fix it might be worth it to close the loophole, I don't expect the filter to be perfect, but this example looks like something it should be able to catch.

Comment: It pains me to see that block of code and know that formatting it would be the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 8):

The 2nd and last lines were not indented so looked like text to the filter.  He got the first line indented by accident.  Nothing malicious, just clumsiness.

A substantial amount of user effort in answering this question got deleted.  I wonder if that was the right call.

Comment: I don't think the filter depends on correctly formatting the code as code, most of the questions it's designed to catch don't have any propoer code formatting.