# Why did both the unformatted code and code dump filters fail on this question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, code-formatting

The question: [Where i did the error? (Php + soap with ws-*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958019/where-i-did-the-error-php-soap-with-ws)

The **[first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/622f54b8-5ad1-4fbf-9f91-43c1d7f0eedc/view-source)** is a code dump, but formatted ... oddly, with newlines inserted at strategic places.  It's as if the user was trying to manually wrap his code at the question border.  How bizarre.

The [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1131976/user1131976) had no rep prior to the question (only downvotes), and is still new to the site.  It sounds like this question should have been caught by the [code dump sniffer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107068/135887), but it wasn't for some reason.  Maybe it was the lack of code formatting?  If so, wouldn't the detection of unformatted code have caught it?   Maybe the wacky newlines threw it off?

Comment: First revision: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8958019/1 looks like a regular question to the filter probably.

Comment: So the actual question is why the "unformatted code" filter wasn't triggered when the question was posted.

Comment: Indeed, I have updated my question to point out that one or the other, or both, failed here.

Comment: I would hate to have the job of the "code dump sniffer"...=)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ultimately, it is a heuristic. Occasionally it will get it wrong; the question is: in which direction (too much blocked / too little blocked) do we want to be wrong? If we tweak it too hard to exclude the absolute craziest of input, we'll probably get more false positives than anything useful. The text as presented isn't even *remotely* markdown-esque, so it is already into a bit of a hit-n-miss territory.

Re your "should have been caught by the code dump sniffer" - that works on **formatted** code; in this case, it wasn't formatted. I'm really not sure that tweaking the unformatted code detection to deal with such a pathological corner-case is useful.

What is important is that **obvious** accidental bad usage is spotted and fixed as early as possible; this deals with the 95% case, without causing noticeable inconvenience (by false positives) to users who are getting it right.