# How to post successfully with large code

Tags: discussion, design, browsers, web

I have some issues in my html code. but unable to post question as it said "it looks like your post is mostly code. please add some more details".

how can we overcome this issue.

Thank you...

Comment: add more details, where, why etc

Comment: The error message tells you to add more details, so you should ... add more details. See also [similar question here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156643/147191).

Comment: If only there was some sort of message indicating why you were unable to ask that particular question....

Answer (score 5):

Are you trying to post a question here, on SO? If so, keep in mind that you should tell us what you're trying to achieve (with possibly some background information), a piece of code (don't paste ALL of your code, just a piece of it) which is relevant to your question. After explaining and showing your code you could add a question if you haven't done so already.

Don't post a question like "my code is not working" followed by a huge amount of code. Be to the point and provide only the information that is necessary. If it's not clear to other people they will let you know.

Hope this helped you :)