# Bug in code dump rejector

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, source-code

The system [rejects code dumps without context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107058/146495) from low-rep users by comparing the ratio of context (non-code-formatted text) to code (text which is wrapped in `<pre>`). (See also [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88842/discourage-code-dumps).)

It seems that this can be circumvented by using tabs instead of 4 spaces, given that [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/20748/revisions) was successfully posted.  I'll admit that I'm not sure exactly where the bug is here.

It could be that the OP, at 161 rep, has graduated above the restriction.  In my opinion, no one should be able to add a post which is 100% code.  We might relax the ratios based on rep, but 100% code is *never* appropriate.

It could be that the code detector discovered that the content of the code block is prose.  It's still formatted as code, and this shouldn't be allowed.

It could be that the code detector missed that this was going to be formatted as code because it used tabs and not spaces.  This seems like the most likely case, given the recent post (that I can't find) about a bug where it allowed an entire post enclosed in backticks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This check is only activated on Stack Overflow, and only for questions. It should also be noted that your example isn't actually code, just mis-formatted prose.

Comment: (1) Why is this check only activated on Stack Overflow, and why is it only for questions? (2) Why should prose formatted as code be allowed?

Comment: (1) Because the code dump problem is largely only a problem on Stack Overflow questions (also, for answers, code-only may be easier to justify). This check is there to help with the "big city" problems that [so] has with its 4k questions per day; no other site comes even close to that. (2) My point is that your example doesn't serve as an example of a a "code dump without context" that would justify turning this check on on [electronics.se] as well.

Comment: I'd like to see a manageable workload  turned into an even more manageable workload by automated processes whenever possible, but I'll accept this reasoning.